# Как передать значение переменной из bash script в fastlane файл

Tags: bash

В fastlane file я подключаю выполняться скрипт следующей командой :

```
test = sh"./bash_script.sh"
```

И в переменную test записывается весь вывод скрипта.

А как мне получить в fastlane значение переменной $result, а не весь вывод  ?

Comment: выведите только значение этой переменной. в чём проблема-то?

Comment: Подавить в скрипте весь вывод кроме необходимого с помощью > /dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

1) Подавить внутри скрипта весь вывод кроме необходимого с помощью `> /dev/null 2>&1`
2) `test="$(sh ./bash_script.sh | tail -1)"` Если строка с результатом выводится последней